# specifying "To" address in SMTP mail settings in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, app-config, smtpclient

Is it possible to set "To" address in SMTP mail settings just like "From" address? there is an attribute for "From", but not "To" address. basically I need to send an email to technical support whenever a specific exception (or any unhandled exception) happens in the application. I can add it to "appSettings", but wondering if I can specify it in SMTP settings itself, without having to read from "appSettings". thanks in advance

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="ben@contoso.com">
        <network host="some server" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot specify the `To` property in the config file. You will need to set it programatically.

Comment: thanks for the reply. since the To mail address is fixed in my case, I was thinking if I can specify it in the settings just like from address

Answer (score 3):

Well, you'll have to set the TO, CC, BCC, Subject, Content and a few other fields when you're calling the SendMail() function from your code.

It wouldn't make sense to define one single TO address as the only thing it would ever do is send mail from `ben@contoso.com` to `jill@contoso.com`.

Comment: For internal use such as app error logging etc sending to a static group is just fine.

Comment: Yes, that may be a very particular use, but if you could have a TO specified in web.config for this very particular case, then you would also need at least one SendMail interface which takes no TO parameter, which on the other hand would lead to hundreds/thousands of people asking on www.stackoverflow.com where they can specify the TO in their function because they want to send emails and the whole feature is broken. This is why MS doesn't provide you the possibility to specify the TO in web.config. For error logging there is the wonderful bundle called Log4Net to skip low level stuff. Havefun