# Mail settings in Web.config

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to set a "to" attribute in the `mailSettings` element in the Web.config file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [specifying "To" address in SMTP mail settings in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428938/specifying-to-address-in-smtp-mail-settings-in-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `Key`

```
   <appSettings>
    <add key="EmailToAddress" value="1337@gmail.com"/> 

</appSettings>
```

And from your codebehind you can get it like this

```
var toAddress= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailToAddress"];
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Kim. It worked when i implemented as key. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ Mr Kim. Done. Am a beginner in stack-overflow . Thats Y. :)

Comment: @Kimtho6 Which node should this snippet go in within the web.config?

Comment: <configuration>
<appSettings>
 <add key="EmailToAddress" value="1337@gmail.com"/>

Answer (score 7):

No, it isn't

Here is the docs for mailSettings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx

Set the default "to" in an AppSetting instead and use that from you mail sending logic.

This is an example taken from the msdn docs:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="ben@contoso.com">
    <network
      host="localhost"
      port="25"
      defaultCredentials="true"
    />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: The original question before it was edited was asking if there was an "to" attribute in the `mailSettings` element in web.config and there isn't.

Comment: When receiving an email it will say from "ben@contoso.com". How could i have it say from "Ben". webconfig will not allow me to set from="Ben<ben@contoso.com>". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I found the solution:

<smtp from="Ben &lt;ben@contoso.com&gt;">

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only specify where the mail is coming `from`:

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, but this would be highly restrictive as you'd likely want to send emails to many different people, perhaps based on some other data.

If you're only sending to one address all the time (such as an admin account) then I recommend just putting the address into the web.config as an 'appSetting' key and reading that instead.